# How String.getBytes() converts string to byte?

Tags: java, arrays, string, byte

When we use `String.getBytes()` on any string, how java internally converts string to byte?, Does it convert string to HEX string and then HEX string to byte?

Comment: I did not check, but it would probably look up the current platform Charset https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html and let it do the conversion. It will not go via some HEX encoding.

Comment: And actualy String is not coverting much, inside a String there is already byte array which stores String value

Comment: Those conversions internally use `java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder` and `java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder` .

Comment: May very much depend on the encoding

Comment: @TomaszBawor but this internal representation would probably not be in the correct encoding.

Answer (score -1):

Use can tell getBytes which Encoding you will use. If do not, Java will use Plattforms Encoding.

```
byte[] bytes = my_input.getBytes ( "UTF-8" )
```